# Events not showing in fullCalendar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to add some Events after the fullCalendar object is create...
I'm working with PHP and JavaScript.

I have create fullCalendar object and after i want to add some events.

Here is the PHP code:

```
  function BuildEvents() { 
    // Showing the calendar 
    echo '<div id="fCald"></div>';

   // Events building
   $evJSON = json_encode(array(
      array('title' => "Evt.1", 
           'start' => "2010-12-22", 
       'url' => "#"),
      array('title' => "Evt.2", 
       'start' => "2011-01-15", 'end' => "2011-01-19",
       'url' => "http://yahoo.com/")
   ));

   // Adding Events to object
   $fCal = '$("#fCald").fullCalendar("addEventSource", '.$evJSON.')';

   //Final showing      
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.
        'eval('.$fCal.');'.
        '</script>';
}
```

When PHP function is call,  the JSON array is OK, but the events are not showing on the calendar...

I also test this code:

```
$fCal = '$("#fCald").fullCalendar("renderEvent", '.$evJSON.', true)';
```

and this is not working to...

I don't understand how to display events after building the fullCalendar object.

Thanks.

Luc M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy/straight forward [example](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar/demos/json.html) in the [plugin page](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: "json-events.php",
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                '(should probably update your database)');
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It work's! In the example, the file is "/myfeed.php" who refer to the "root directory". Now, I use "myfeed.php" and I put the file in the "current directory"...

Comment: I have a second question. Is it possible to view french characters in the events? When I try PHP function utf8_encode() or the entities like (&eacute;), it's not working...

Comment: OK! I found the solution. You must apply utf8_encode() to the title text BEFORE calling json_encode()...